# PropertyChanged is null

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

First I also thought that's a small problem but I really don't know how to solve it!

I wrote my one "Point" class to implement PropertyChanged but it does not work because "PropertyChanged==null" is true.

Here mySource:

```
public class RaPoint : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RaPoint() : this(0,0)
    {
    }

    public RaPoint(double X, double Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public RaPoint(Point Position)
        : this(Position.X, Position.Y)
    {
    }

    public RaPoint(RaPoint Position)
        : this(Position.X, Position.Y)
    {
    }

    public static RaPoint operator +(RaPoint P1, Vector V1)
    {
        P1.X += V1.X;
        P1.Y += V1.Y;
        return P1;
    }

    public double X
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(XProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(XProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(double), typeof(RaPoint), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
    {
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
        DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    }
    );


    public double Y
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(YProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double), typeof(RaPoint), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
    {
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
        DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    }
    );


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("X:{0} Y:{1}", X.ToString(), Y.ToString());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public void Set(double X, double Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public void Set(RaPoint Position)
    {
        Set(Position.X, Position.Y);
    }

    public void Set(Point Position)
    {
        Set(Position.X, Position.Y);
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: I get the feeling you mixed something up. Either you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use dependency properties. Where and how will you use this class?

Comment: I assume you're binding to `X` and `Y` properties? Not 100% sure but I think, the Presentation won't subscribe to your `PropertyChanged` since you're registered `DependencyProperties` here. The `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `DependencyProperty` are two exclusive scenarios IMO.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that I'm not allowed to use both in the same value!! Thank you!
Am I allowed to use both in one class?

Comment: @MisterPresident: What's your reasoning for using a dependency property?  I write tons of WPF and have seldom needed to use it, so I'm curious.  In my opinion, implementing only INotifyPropertyChanged is the cleanest and most simplistic way to notify the View of changes.  Unless, of course, I'm missing the use case..

Comment: I have an Element with a position - this position is bond to differen other positions in subproperties via a converter.
Am I doing this in a wrong way?

Comment: Could you please post the client C#-code which sets up the data for binding (for example, by using `DataContext` property setter) and also appropriate XAML-code?

Answer (score -2):

Did you set the correct value on the object DataContext? For example: this.DataContext = raPoint;